# Trouble with a Case statement containing CharIndex

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can't figure out why this says 'incorrect synax near >'

```
    case changeuserid
    when charindex('toolbar',lower(changeuserid) > 0 then 'TOOLBAR'
    when charindex('mflynn',lower(changeuserid) > 0 then 'MFLYNN'
else (select username from CLAIMSAUDIT_USERS where MC400ID_PHP=changeuserid)    
end AS 'dbusername',
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing closing paren on the `charindex()`.  In addition, your `case` syntax is incorrect.  You have an extra `changeuserid`:

```
(case when charindex('toolbar', lower(changeuserid)) > 0 then 'TOOLBAR'
      when charindex('mflynn', lower(changeuserid)) > 0 then 'MFLYNN'
      else (select username from CLAIMSAUDIT_USERS where MC400ID_PHP = changeuserid)    
 end) AS 'dbusername',
```

Comment: Thank you.  I know that was a silly one - but I am not very experienced in t-sql and sometimes it is the smaller things that trip me up.  I see all of those mistakes now, and the fact that I was trying to use the wrong version of Case (with a full expression inside).  Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below format of `case` , Also there is syntax error due to missing `)` bracket before `>`

```
case 
    when charindex('toolbar',lower(changeuserid)) > 0 then 'TOOLBAR'
    when charindex('mflynn',lower(changeuserid) ) > 0 then 'MFLYNN'
    else (select username from CLAIMSAUDIT_USERS where MC400ID_PHP=changeuserid)    
end AS 'dbusername'
```